# Cocoa : Multiline NSTextFieldCell in a NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, nsoutlineview, nstextfieldcell

I am developing a Cocoa application.

I have a NSOutlineView displaying custom cells ( cells inherits from NSTextFieldCell). The problem I am facing to is that the cell text is only displayed on one line... how can I have a multiline textField ???

Thanks for reading ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Configure your table column's dataCell to wrap instead of scroll with -[NSCell setWraps:]
2. Implement -[NSObject outlineView: heightOfRowByItem:] in your outline view delegate.
3. Use -[NSCell cellSizeForBounds:] to find the height of the cell for a specific width. For cellSizeForBounds:, you can pass a really tall rectangle that's the width of your column, and it will return a smaller rectangle that is the right height for the text to fit in that width.

Comment: Hey Jon, can you please post an example of your Step 3. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you wanted to know how tall your text was for a width of 100, you would invoke something like this: [cell cellSizeForBounds:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 10000)].height